# Does Primary Interop Assemblies ( PIA ) require Microsoft Office to be installed in the machine to work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, interop, office-interop, com-interop

Does Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA) require Microsoft Office to be installed on the machine in order to use?

I have gone through so many confusing post/sites and am unable to arrive at a conclusion.

I have a machine where Office is not installed and I am using VS2010. The `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly was not available in COM section under reference. I added it through the .Net section in references but it still throws the below error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID   failed due
> to the following error: 80040154  Class not registered (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Here is the statement from Microsoft's website: [The Office PIAs are not required on end-user computers to run Office solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx). What does this mean exactly? Does it mean without Office installation we can work with interop assemblies? If not, why do they require PIA when Office needs to be installed to make it work?

Comment: Well, what do you think of a business strategy of a company that sells a software product for many hundreds of dollars and allows you to embed that product into your program and distribute it freely?  The exception message tells you what strategy they used.

Comment: @HansPassant  I know there is no free lunch here . Can you please let know what does they mean by  "The Office PIAs are not required on end-user computers to run Office solutions "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does Primary Interop Assemblies ( PIA ) require Microsoft Office to be installed in the machine to work ?

Yes.

The PIA are simply assemblies that allow you to call the Office COM object model from .NET. The COM objects which are hosted by the Office applications still need to be present for this to work. The *Class not registered* error you get is because the COM object is missing on the computer. To fix that you need to install the version of Office your application is designed to work with.

Comment: PIAs have been obsolete for the past 5 years.  Elegantly replaced by the Embed Interop Types feature available since .NET 4.0 and VS2010.  There are no PIAs anymore for Office 2013, they won't come back.

Comment: @dbardakov I'm confused about your comment. I'm not saying that you cannot embed PIAs in your app. You have been able to do that forever if I remember correctly. I'm saying that Office has to be installed for you app to be able to automate Office. If Office isn't installed then you get an error like the one described in the question.

Answer (score 7):

> This is statement from Mircosoft website , The Office PIAs are not required on end-user computers to run Office solutions . What does this mean exactly ?

That's not the current quote I find. The one I find is:

> The PIAs must also be installed on end-user computers to run Office solutions that target the .NET Framework 3.5. However, the Office PIAs are not required on end-user computers to run Office solutions that target the .NET Framework 4. For more information, see Designing and Creating Office Solutions. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hy7c6z9k(v=vs.100).aspx)

It means (for net 4+) that when you create an Office Solution in VS usint PIAs, you do not need to install those PIAs on the target computer to be able to run the solution. (the reason is because, if you've targeted Net4, if the Embed Interop Types property of each Office PIA reference in the project is set to True (this is the default value), the type information for the PIA types that are used by your solution is embedded into the solution assembly when you build the project. At run time, the embedded type information is used instead of the PIAs to call into the Office application's COM-based object model. For more information about how types from PIAs are embedded into your solution (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3295w01c(v=vs.100).aspx)

For example: I want to write a program in VB to doSomething on an XLSX sheet.

I have to install Excel, PIA, and VS on my development machine or I will not be able to write it.

Once this program is finished, I want Bob in accounting to run it. So I publish the program and it gets installed on Bob's machine. Bob will not need to have installed PIAs on his local machine to run the program. He *will* need office.

> Does it mean without Office installation we can work with interop assemblies ?

The other way around. It means, with Net 4+ applications using PIA (EIT), your application can work without PIAs installed on the client machine (the needed pieces will be part of your deployment).

Comment: As a side note worth considering - embedded interop types [can be tricky](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/type-equivalence-and-embedded-interop-types). You may want to encapsulate all the work with Excel in a single project in solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your question really has two parts:

1. What does a **developer** need to *develop* an application that makes use of Office components?
2. What does an **end user** need to *run* that application?

On MSDN, the article [Office Solutions Development Overview (Visual Studio 2013)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy7c6z9k%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) provides concise guidance for these questions. From the section "Automating Office Applications by Using Primary Interop Assemblies":

> You must have the Office PIAs installed and registered in the global
>   assembly cache on your development computer to perform most
>   development tasks. For more information, see [Configuring a Computer
>   to Develop Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242(v=vs.120).aspx). The Office PIAs are not required on
>   end-user computers to run Office solutions. For more information, see
>   [Designing and Creating Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3295w01c(v=vs.120).aspx).

The first article makes it clear that the developer must install Microsoft Office:

> To create add-ins and customizations for Microsoft Office, install a
>   supported version of Visual Studio, the .NET Framework, and Microsoft
>   Office.

And from the latter article in the section "Understanding When the Office PIAs Are Required on End User Computers":

> By default, Office primary interop assemblies (PIAs) do not need to be
>   installed on end user computers if the **Embed Interop Types**
>   property of each Office PIA reference in the project is set to
>   **True**, which is the default value. In this scenario, the type information for the PIA types that are used by your solution is
>   embedded into the solution assembly when you build the project. At run
>   time, the embedded type information is used instead of the PIAs to
>   call into the Office application's COM-based object model. For more
>   information about how types from PIAs are embedded into your solution,
>   see [Type Equivalence and Embedded Interop Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297(v=vs.120).aspx).